# duda sobre este codigo

Tags: c++, visual-studio

referente a este codigo para calcular notas ,pero tengo las sgtes dudas, se que el n es como un liminator (vale 2) pero que funcion hace el aux y el n1?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct alumno
{   char nombre[100];
    double t1, t2, ep, ef;
};
double promAula(alumno A[], int n, double aux,int n1){
    if (n == 0)
        return aux/ n1;
    else {
        double p = A[n - 1].t1*0.15 + A[n - 1].t2*0.15 +
            A[n - 1].ep*0.3 + A[n - 1].ef*0.4;
        aux += p;
        return promAula(A, n - 1, aux, n1);
    }
}
void main(){
alumno A[5]; 
int n = 2; 
double pa = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "Nombre: "; cin >> A[i].nombre;
        cout << "T1: "; cin >> A[i].t1;
        cout << "T2: "; cin >> A[i].t2;
        cout << "EP: "; cin >> A[i].ep;
        cout << "EF: "; cin >> A[i].ef;
    }
    cout << "Promedio Aula: " << promAula(A, n, pa, n);
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bien, te comento:

En tu código, la variable aux funciona como un contador que almacena las notas de cada alumno y las va sumando. Y, la variable n1 funciona como contador de alumnos, no se incrementa ni nada, sino que almacena la cantidad de alumnos que hay.

Cuando la función recursiva, termina de analizar la estructura alumnos, lo que hace es devolver aux/n1, que se traduce como, la suma de todas las notas de los alumnos, divida por la cantidad de alumnos que hay.